# How to install "libhyperic-sigar-java" in CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, rpm, yum, sigar

> libhyperic-sigar-java: (System Information Gatherer And Reporter - Java bindings)

I know the way to install "libhyperic-sigar-java" in ubuntu to use

```
sudo apt-get install libhyperic-sigar-java
```

Now I want to install libhyperic-sigar-java in CentOS

How should I do ? Any RPM I can use ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using java, take a look to **Kamon Sigar Loader**

Provides convenient self-contained [Sigar](https://github.com/hyperic/sigar) 
classes with native library deployment and provisioning mechanism with JDK-only dependencies
for the following common use cases:

- Java Agent: automatic extract/load at JVM start time
- Programmatically: embedded library extraction
- Framework Contract: OSGI bundle activation

[here](https://github.com/kamon-io/sigar-loader/tree/master/core/src/main/resources) the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `yum`. First search for the exact package name:

```
yum search java
```

then when you have found the exact name:

```
yum install libhyperic-sigar-java
```

(or whatever the exact package name might be)

Comment: There's no any sigar package I can install, no matches found

Comment: then there are two options: 1. you search the sigar rpm on the internet, download it and install it. 2. you search the sigar rpm on the internet, look what is the repository in which it is located and add that repository

Comment: because I can't find out the rpm before so that I asked this question, finally I got the solution. I download sigar deb pkg and converted to rpm. probably It can work. thanks for your suggestion.